Connection refused to mongodb after converting standalone to primary only replicaset
I got troble now.
After I converted my standalone mongodb on ec2 to replica set of primary only,
I cannot connect to db with admin user.
So, I looked into mongodb log but there is only "accepted" and "ended", no error message.
Here is mongod log
{"t":{"$date":"2024-07-10T09:15:44.340+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"119.66.58.231:60474","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"49132c53-5b33-4542-800f-4c940c842162"}},"connectionId":10,"connectionCount":6}} 
{"t":{"$date":"2024-07-10T09:15:44.342+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn10","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"119.66.58.231:60474","client":"conn10","negotiatedCompressors":[],"doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Compass"},"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"6.7.0"},"platform":"Node.js v20.9.0, LE","os":{"name":"darwin","architecture":"arm64","version":"23.4.0","type":"Darwin"}}}} 
{"t":{"$date":"2024-07-10T09:15:44.352+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn10","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"119.66.58.231:60474","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"49132c53-5b33-4542-800f-4c940c842162"}},"connectionId":10,"connectionCount":5}}

I set security.keyFile for converting because got message this : mongod badvalue: security.keyfile is required when authorization is enabled with replica sets
Maybe it is cause of problem??
Plase help me!!
I tried change connection URI string by adding replicaSet  like this.
mongodb://admin:{password}@{primary ip}:27017/?replicaSet=devrs0
But not works still

Did you create a keyfile and copied the file to all replica set members?

@WernfriedDomscheit it is now just primary only replica set. So, I didn't copied. just set keyFile path to /etc/mongod.conf after rs.initiate()

Just must copy the keyfile, even with only one member. Otherwise it does not start.

Is the mongod process starting? Does it stay running?

@Joe Yeah, so I made keyfile in /etc/ and primary use this key so mongod started and run so that I can see above log lines.

Now I found it I can connecto add param directConnection=true. But in this case, my connection is for standalone, right? I need to use replicaset because transaction query is only available on replica set. How can I connect on replicaset?

Bad host name in the replica set configuration document?
